# Lovely ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: css, angular, typescript

**I have**

- Input to enter a Student email or IAM > it will be added to an string[]
- List with all the listed students I added > with a for loop, as you can see below
- Button to delete a Student from the Array

The List has a 'maxHeight' and I need to check when the content is higher than the 'scrollHeight', show a button to read more, otherwise hide it.

I got it work, but I have an issue with it, when I add so many students that the height is above the 'maxHeight', he shows the button, that works perfectly, but, when I delete more students until it should hide the button again, then the error will be triggered.

*SetTimeout is not a solution for me, except there will be no other solution*

```
<div class="input-row">
  <input #studentsInput
         (keypress)="onKeyPressStudent($event, studentsInput)"
         class="input-field"
         placeholder="Student Email or IAM"
         required
         type="text">
</div>

<ul #listStudents
    [ngClass]="{ 'scrollable': studentsScroll }"
    class="list-row">
  <li *ngFor="let student of students; index as i"
      class="list-item">
    {{ student }}

    <span (click)="deleteStudent(i)"
          class="material-icons">
      close
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="listStudents.offsetHeight < listStudents.scrollHeight"
     class="more">
  <span class="material-icons">
    more_horiz
  </span>
</div>
```

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  public students: string[] = [];
  public studentsScroll = false;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public onKeyPressStudent(
    event: KeyboardEvent,
    studentsInput: HTMLInputElement,
  ): void {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      if (studentsInput.checkValidity()) {
        this.students.push(studentsInput.value);
        studentsInput.value = '';
      } else {
        this.toastrService.error('Please enter a valid Email Address!');
      }
    }
  }

  public deleteStudent(index: number): void {
    this.students.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public toggleStudentScroll(): void {
    this.studentsScroll = !this.studentsScroll;
  }
}
```

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxhgt.png)

Comment: Maybe add setTimeout?

Comment: @LightZumo : Psssst :)

Comment: can you share your ts code?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko of course, there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deleteStudent(), the students array gets mutated (splice) and the number of list items (li) changes due to the *ngFor directive used. This causes the listStudents element property changes (offsetHeight, scrollHeight) that are bound to the *ngIf directive.

So the expression "listStudents.offsetHeight < listStudents.scrollHeight" changes after the change detection (triggered by students array mutated) ran through the template.

To fix the issue you need to ensure that the check (show/hide the button) happens outside of the initial CD (that is why setTimeout works as it creates its own CD).

You could achieve that by using afterContentChecked lifeCycle hook:
https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentChecked

And assess if "showmore" should be in DOM (true) or not (false) by evaluating the statement you have inside that hook:

```
<div class="input-row">
  <input #studentsInput
         (keypress)="onKeyPressStudent($event, studentsInput)"
         class="input-field"
         placeholder="Student Email or IAM"
         required
         type="text">
</div>

<ul #listStudents
    [ngClass]="{ 'scrollable': studentsScroll }"
    class="list-row">
  <li *ngFor="let student of students; index as i"
      class="list-item">
    {{ student }}

    <span (click)="deleteStudent(i)"
          class="material-icons">
      close
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="showmore" class="more">
  <span class="material-icons">
    more_horiz
  </span>
</div>
```

In ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('listStudents', { static: true }) listStudents: ElementRef;
  private listStudentsNativeElement: HTMLElement;

  public showmore: boolean = false;

  public students: string[] = [];
  public studentsScroll = false;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public onKeyPressStudent(
    event: KeyboardEvent,
    studentsInput: HTMLInputElement,
  ): void {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      if (studentsInput.checkValidity()) {
        this.students.push(studentsInput.value);
        studentsInput.value = '';
      } else {
        console.log('Please enter a valid Email Address!');
      }
    }
  }

  public deleteStudent(index: number): void {
    this.students.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public toggleStudentScroll(): void {
    this.studentsScroll = !this.studentsScroll;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listStudentsNativeElement = this.listStudents.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.listStudentsNativeElement) {
      this.showmore = (this.listStudentsNativeElement.offsetHeight < this.listStudentsNativeElement.scrollHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

Few notes:

- we need to get listStudents nativeElement reference after full init (ngAfterViewInit)
- we still have to check if the listStudents nativeElement is defined as the ngAfterContentChecked fires before the view initialization

I the other way around is to use setTimeout or RequestAnimationFrame API:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('listStudents', { static: true }) listStudents: ElementRef;
  private listStudentsNativeElement: HTMLElement;

  public showmore: boolean = false;
  public students: string[] = [];
  public studentsScroll = false;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public onKeyPressStudent(
    event: KeyboardEvent,
    studentsInput: HTMLInputElement,
  ): void {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      if (studentsInput.checkValidity()) {
        this.students.push(studentsInput.value);
        studentsInput.value = '';
        this.checkForShowMore();
      } else {
        console.log('Please enter a valid Email Address!');
      }
    }
  }

  public deleteStudent(index: number): void {
    this.students.splice(index, 1);
    this.checkForShowMore();
  }

  public toggleStudentScroll(): void {
    this.studentsScroll = !this.studentsScroll;
  }

  checkForShowMore() {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      this.showmore = (this.listStudentsNativeElement.offsetHeight < this.listStudentsNativeElement.scrollHeight);
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listStudentsNativeElement = this.listStudents.nativeElement;
  }

}
```